# JavaMail search by subject fails for certain substrings

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I have few emails with a subject like `Report #123 : "Email_test_856" from test`. I am trying to use the JavaMail API to find messages based on the keyword `Email_test`, however it doesn't filter out any messages.

Here is the code I've used:

```
public Message[] getMessages(String emailSubject, Folder folderInbox) throws MessagingException {
       Message[] foundMessages = folderInbox.search(new SubjectTerm(emailSubject));
       return foundMessages;
}
```

However, if I do a search with subject as `Email_test_856` or `from test`, the message get filtered.

Also, if I have mails with subject as `Report #123 : "Email test 856" from test`, a search with keyword `Email test` works perfectly.

Comment: Is it an IMAP server?

Comment: Yes it is an IMAP server.

Comment: Then I would answer the same as given as below. Searching in a folder is a faster operation since it's handled by the mail server. But may not always give you what you expect if it's GMail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Gmail?  Gmail will only find strings that are entire words.  See the list of [Gmail restrictions in the FAQ](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/Gmail)

Comment: Yes I'm using Gmail, is there any other way to do substring search (apart from me actually implementing the search on top of all messages)?

Comment: Not that I know of.  It's a limitation of Gmail.